# How to create custom project file that works with fast-up-to-date (and avoids other problems)?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to create a project file that performs few custom steps (specifically, it "wraps" existing Angular CLI project).

Here is my best attempt (`myproject.csproj`):

```
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" DefaultTargets="Build">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectGuid>{...some-guid...}</ProjectGuid>
    <!-- do not include files by default -->
    <EnableDefaultItems>false</EnableDefaultItems>
    <!-- this removes 'Publish...' menu in VS -->
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <!-- output directory name -->
    <AngularProject>MyWebFiles</AngularProject>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <AngularFile Include="**" Exclude="node_modules\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Build" Inputs="@(AngularFile)" Outputs="$(OutputPath)$(AngularProject)\index.html">
    <Exec Command="ng build --no-progress --output-path $(OutputPath)$(AngularProject)\" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'" />
    <Exec Command="ng build --no-progress --output-path $(OutputPath)$(AngularProject)\ --prod" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'" />
  </Target>
  
  <Target Name="Clean">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(OutputPath)$(AngularProject)\" />
  </Target>
  
  <Target Name="Rebuild" DependsOnTargets="Clean;Build" />
</Project>
```

Everything works fine, I can add this project to VS2019 solution, compile, etc. But it has problems:

1. Fast up-to-date check doesn't work. [Related logging](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/blob/main/docs/up-to-date-check.md#net-framework-projects) produces this:

```
  Build started...
  1>Project 'myproject' is not up to date. Error (0x8000FFFF).
```

I've tried specifying fast up-to-date files [manually](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/blob/main/docs/up-to-date-check.md#customization) (via `UpToDateCheckInput`, etc), but it didn't work (presumably because it relies on additional definitions pulled in when you specify `Sdk` attribute of `Project` tag).

2. VS configuration manager has empty 'Platform' combo box. I'd like to be able to have `x64` in it:

[image: 1]

it is rather obvious that `PlatformTarget` is getting ignored by VS.

3. Opening project in VS results in creation of `obj\x64\Debug\TempPE\` directory (if current `Configuration` is `Debug`). Nothing ever gets generated in it -- would be nice to avoid it being created.

Is it possible to fix these 3 problems? I suspect relates subsystems expect certain values/properties to be generated, I've tried digging in `.props/.targets` that come with VS in attempt to locate them, but quickly got lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.Build.NoTargets/3.2.14">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.NoTargets" Version="3.2.14" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Any target framework you want as long as its compatible with your referenced NuGet packages -->
    <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
    <!-- Do not add TargetFramework to OutputPath -->
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <!-- Do not expect pdb files to be generated (this is for fast up-to-date check) -->
    <DebugType>None</DebugType>
    <!-- Do not include files by default -->
    <EnableDefaultItems>false</EnableDefaultItems>
    <!-- Output subdir name -->
    <AngularProject>MyWebFiles</AngularProject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <OutputPath>..\..\Bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <BuildCommand>ng build --no-progress --output-path $(OutputPath)$(AngularProject)\</BuildCommand>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <OutputPath>..\..\Bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <BuildCommand>ng build --no-progress --output-path $(OutputPath)$(AngularProject)\ --prod</BuildCommand>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="**" Exclude="node_modules\**;$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)\**;$(MSBuildProjectFile)" />
    
    <!-- This deals with fast up-to-date checks -->
    <UpToDateCheckBuilt Original="package-lock.json" Include="node_modules/.build" />
    
    <UpToDateCheckInput Include="@(None);$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Set="AngularFiles" />
    <UpToDateCheckOutput Include="$(OutputPath)$(AngularProject)\index.html" Set="AngularFiles" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="InitModules" Inputs="package-lock.json" Outputs="node_modules/.build">
    <Exec Command="npm ci --no-progress --no-color" YieldDuringToolExecution="true" />
    <Exec Command="cd . &gt; node_modules/.build" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="BuildAngular" BeforeTargets="AfterBuild" Inputs="@(None);$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Outputs="$(OutputPath)$(AngularProject)\index.html" DependsOnTargets="InitModules">
    <Exec Command="$(BuildCommand)" YieldDuringToolExecution="true" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="CleanAngular" BeforeTargets="AfterClean">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(OutputPath)$(AngularProject)\" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Notes:

- it will still generate additional local directory (`obj`), but it can be moved away by overriding `IntermediateOutputPath`

**EDIT:** Recent versions of VS2019 refuse to load such project -- you need to install `.NET SDK (out of support)` individual component (in Visual Studio Installer`) to fix that.